# Confusion interpreting an amplifier module's cut off frequency from its datasheet

Tags: amplifier

In an amplifier module's data-sheet the section about the filter switch is given as:

[image]

The mechanical switch sets the amplifier to 10hz or 6kHz LP filter setting.

I have the following questions:

1-) What does "change-over" mean here?

2-) Normally cut off is defined for 3dB point which means at cut off the outpout power is halve the input power. Here what does -1dB mean?

Comment: here is the whole pdf http://www.celiss.com/products/files201666171658371066109.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's not clear what 'changeover' means here, it's probably a bad translation from another language. Fortunately, 3rd order Bessel lowpass filter is unambiguous. Bessel means a lowpass filter response which is free of time domain overshoots, ideal for measurement applications. If you put a step change into it, the output will rise monotonically to the final value, sharper filters like Butterworth or Chebychev would overshoot the final value before settling down.

Changeover might refer to the change between passing low frequency signals and blocking high frequency ones, or it might refer to the switch being able to change the response between 10Hz and 6kHz, who knows?

2) Normally, cutoff is defined as whatever it's defined as. If there's no figure supplied, then it often means the -3dB point. Here, it *is* defined, and as the -1dB point.

What's being defined is the flatness of the passband up to the specified frequency. It's quite common in measurement applications to specify a flatter passband than for (say) audio. -1dB means about 10% error, whereas -3dB would be about 30% error.

Given that we're told the shape of the filter, we can use standard curves to estimate the -3dB point from the -1dB point. For -1dB at 10Hz, a 3rd order Bessel will be -3dB at roughly 16Hz.

Comment: FWIW, I agree with @Neil_UK. The term 'changeover' is probably a bad translation. My first impression, based on the context, is that 'changeover' means  'selectable'--i.e., "3rd-order selectable low-pass filter (10 Hz or 6 kHz)."  And considering this spec's context is "Measurement frequency range", the OEM is likely specifying the passband's upper frequency limit as 10 Hz (or 6 kHz) @ -1 dB.

Comment: Im sorry but does that mean this filter has 3dB at 10Hz? Like usual?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you don't seem to get that the amplifier is **specified to be -1dB at 10Hz**. Like usual, what the words say is what they mean, not something else. Given that it's specified to be a 3rd order Bessel filter, you can estimate the -3dB frequency from standard curves, to be about 16Hz.

Comment: Thanks I reread your answer I somehow skipped the last paragraph. I got it now.

Comment: Sorry about that. You didn't miss the last paragraph, I added it after your comment so that all the info was in the answer.